# GWT overlay types accesing keywords

Tags: gwt

The following code is not working because "default" seems to be a JavaScript keyword.
Is there an easy way of fixing this? I want to avoid to change the name on the server side.

```
    public final native boolean getDefault() /*-{
    return this.default;
}-*/;
```

Thanks in advance

kukudas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array access instead of variable access:

```
return this['default'];
```